# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: sql, string, winforms, format

I have a class in which i calculate the credit limit left. And return the values through a DataTable. But in the IF condition it is throwing error 'Input string was not in a correct format.', Whats wrong in the code.

Please Help,
Thanks in Advance

```
        string cmd2 = "select sum(FacilityAmountINR),sum(LCAmountPaid) from FacilityIssueDetails where Status='open' AND LCType = 'Inland LC'";
        DataTable a = DbRdRw.SqlDbRead(cmd2, "FacilityIssueDetails");
        decimal AvailInlandLC = 0;
        string totcred = Convert.ToString(a.Rows[0]["Column1"]);
        string totpaid = Convert.ToString(a.Rows[0]["Column2"]);
        if (totcred != null && totpaid != null)
        {
            decimal TotalAmountCredit = Convert.ToDecimal(totcred);// error here
            decimal TotalAmountpaid = Convert.ToDecimal(totpaid); // error here
            AvailInlandLC = InlandLC - TotalAmountCredit + TotalAmountpaid;
        }
        //*************************************************************************
        DataTable AvailableLimitTable = new DataTable();
        AvailableLimitTable.Columns.Add("LCType",typeof (string));
        AvailableLimitTable.Columns.Add("TotalLimit",typeof (decimal));
        AvailableLimitTable.Columns.Add("AvailableLimit",typeof (decimal));

        DataRow dr = AvailableLimitTable.NewRow();
        dr["LCType"] = "Inland LC";
        dr["TotalLimit"] = InlandLC;
        dr["AvailableLimit"] = AvailInlandLC;
        AvailableLimitTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
```

Comment: Have you set some breakpoints to check what the values of those variables are when the error is thrown?

Comment: the database is throwing NULL value as there is no data in table
this code be=ecomes useless wen a new bank will be inserted coz there will be no entriea and DataTable a will return null

Comment: But obviously `totcred` and `totpaid` are not `null` when the code hits this line `if (totcred != null && totpaid != null)`. So what is their value then? Check for that by updating your `if` statement.

Comment: if(totcred != "" && totpaid != "" )

i wrote this and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the if loop condition if you are getting NULL value from database...

```
if (totcred != null && totpaid != null && totcred != "Null" && totpaid != "Null" )
        {
            decimal TotalAmountCredit = Convert.ToDecimal(totcred);// error here
            decimal TotalAmountpaid = Convert.ToDecimal(totpaid); // error here
            AvailInlandLC = InlandLC - TotalAmountCredit + TotalAmountpaid;
        }
```

Comment: it worked but there are some changes though
          if(totcred != "" && totpaid != "" )// coz value was ""

Thanks for help